# Import a 3D CSV file results in the wrong dimensions

Tags: export, import, csv-format

I exported a some of my data to a file, the data looks like this before the export

```
Dimensions[mydata]
{129}

Dimensions[mydata[[1]]]
Dimensions[mydata[[3]]]
 {36, 2}
 {16, 2}

mydata[[1, 5]]
mydata[[1, 5, 1]]
 {4.94378, 400.06}
 4.94378

Export["mydata.csv", mydata];
```

When I import it this is what it looks like:

```
myimportdata = Import["mydata.csv"];

Dimensions[myimportdata]
 {129}

Dimensions[myimportdata[[1]]]
Dimensions[myimportdata[[3]]]
 {36}
 {16}

myimportdata[[1, 5]]
myimportdata[[1, 5, 1]]
 {4.943784497, 400.06}
 Part specification {{{0, 0},{0.000345398, 0.03},{4.004763899, 200.02},{4.845128134, 200.11},
```

How can I fix this? So far I have tried Flatten and Partition but that didn't work. Is it treating the in inner pairs as a string? Any help would be great.

Comment: Is it possible to save a multidimensional dataset to CSV?  I thought CSV would just be for a 2D array, just rows and columns, but clearly I'm wrong since your imported data has more than that.  Can we have a small subset of `mydata` to work with?

Comment: Here you go:                                                                                         {{0, 0}, {0.000345398, 0.03}, {4.00476, 200.02}, {4.84513, 
  200.11}, {4.94378, 400.06}, {7.2857, 447.27}}, {{0, 
  0}, {0.000126261, 0.03}, {1.98535, 1.*10^6}, {2.93083, 
  1.*10^6}}, {{0, 0}, {0.000152619, 0.03}, {2.27639, 
  200.02}, {2.51146, 200.11}, {2.8589, 400.06}, {3.44741, 
  1.*10^6}}, {{0, 0}, {0.000086549, 0.03}, {1.27432, 200.02}, {2.8542,
   3.93865*10^6}, {2.99701, 7.5813*10^6}}                                           Ok whats the recommended format to export this data?

Comment: @MikeLimaOscar, That did it thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Since your array has more than two dimensions (and is not full dimensional)
`Export` writes the "extra dimensions" as strings.  A MWE:

```
d = {Table[a + b, {a, 2}, {b, 2}], Table[a + b, {a, 3}, {b, 2}]}
```

> {{{2, 3}, {3, 4}}, {{2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}}}

```
Dimensions[d]
Dimensions /@ d
```

> {2}
>
> {{2, 2}, {3, 2}}

No surprises there!

```
Export["mydata.csv", d];
FilePrint[%]
```

> "{2, 3}","{3, 4}"
>
> "{2, 3}","{3, 4}","{4, 5}"

You can read the data in using:

```
Import["mydata.csv"] /. x_String :> ToExpression[x]
```